# I want to slightly randomise the values of integers within an atribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

I have a map with height data, but the height data is not very fine and detailed and the map is quite large. For my purposes, which is fantasy cartography, I can simply randomize data a little. My thought process is I can generate points from the map, and if I am correct, those points should inherit the map layer's height data atribute (which exists). Please correct me if I am wrong about the points automatically having the height attributes from the cells below them. This is my first time using any GIS software.

Once those points exist, is there any way I can use a function to read the attribute data, and then randomly add or subtract a random number between -10 and 10 to the height attribute? I figure that would let me create a nicer and more natural-looking DEM.

Comment: While it's possible to mask in a random raster, you might be better off just low-pass filtering the content, as is recommended on all integer DEMs.

Comment: I don't know what that means, could you explain or provide a link to a reference? The only low-pass filter I know of is the audio editing version, haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the points exist and have their height values assigned from your coarse DEM, you can use the [`QGIS Field Calculator`](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) to apply the random disturbance to the existing height values such as original_ht. This is what the field calculator would look like:

```
$z = $z + rand(-10,10)
```

which you can probably observe as "the new height = the old height + a random value between -10 and 10."

I recommend creating a column storing the "original DEM height" named, I don't know, `original_dem_ht`, so that you can perform the calculation over and over again until you like the results.

```
original_dem_ht = $z /*do this once only*/

$z = original_dem_ht + rand(-10,10) /*iterate on the values until you like the look of the results*/
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I am looking for. It worked a treat.